# Howto make a inteactive chosen menu in Python2 CLI?

Tags: python, menu, command-line-interface

Howto make a interactive menu in terminal? example:

[image]

Need a menu with multiple options and navigate with arrows keys of keyboard and enter to select.

Comment: Perhaps `curses` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A great tool for this is `py_cui` - it provides a very complete command line interface framework. Here's a demo from their docs:

https://jwlodek.github.io/py_cui-docs/

[image: py_cui example]

Also - `pythondialog` can do command line dialog interfaces:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pythondialog/

[image: pythondialog example]

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this menu I designed. I did it on Linux without using an external library

https://github.com/rzakaan/terminal-menu

[image]

Comment: Hello Rza, welcome to StackOverflow! The question you are trying to answer is about 4 years old. I doubt the op will respond. You may want to flag this answer "need for moderation" and note to the admins that "This post is 4 years old and already has an answer". This may get you a "helpful" flag. ;)